# IllegalStateException: What does it mean?

Tags: java, illegalstateexception

Can someone explain why i could get the following error?

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Peer does not exist while invoking
>   the increaseComponentCount() method   at
>   java.awt.Container.increaseComponentCount(Container.java:3978)    at
>   java.awt.Component.addNotify(Component.java:6917)     at
>   java.awt.Container.addNotify(Container.java:2758)     at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.addNotify(JComponent.java:4743)    at
>   java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1114)   at
>   javax.swing.CellRendererPane.addImpl(CellRendererPane.java:106)   at
>   java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:410)    at
>   javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(CellRendererPane.java:134)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCell(BasicTableUI.java:2115)
>     at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paintCells(BasicTableUI.java:2016)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableUI.paint(BasicTableUI.java:1812)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:161)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:778)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1054)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5221)     at
>   javax.swing.BufferStrategyPaintManager.paint(BufferStrategyPaintManager.java:295)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1206)   at
>   javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5169)    at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4980)     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:770)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:728)
>     at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:677)
>     at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:59)    at
>   javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1621)
>     at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:705)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:101)   at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:666)    at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:664)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:675)   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:128)
>     at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:121)
>     at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:182)
>     at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:221)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Can you please add the code.snippet where it happens? Which values have your variables before the error is thrown? You should get them setting a breakpoint and using debugger.

Comment: It looks like you are cross-threading with the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have some threading issue. Are you overriding incorrectly addNotify() by any chance?

http://mindprod.com/jgloss/addnotify.html

Comment: You are right. But I see this issue with JAVA 1.7 only, with 1.6 i dont see this.